# Finding minimum column count from data rows in Excel C#

Tags: c#, excel-interop

In an Excel document suppose there are data as shown below:

**1 a**
**2 b c**
3 d e f
4 g h i j k
5 l m n

Considering the very first two rows being header, data rows are from the third line. How could the minimum column count can be found from this data given that is 3, because for all rows to have common data into the all columns.

What I have is two classes as shown below

```
 public class RowEntity
 {
     public List<String> ColumnValues { get; set; }
 }
 public class FileEntity
 {
     public List<RowEntity> RowValues { get; set; }
 }
```

Data rows can be accessed may be like below:

```
List <RowEntity> dataRows = fileObj.RowValues.GetRange(int index, int count);
```

I need to have something like:

```
    private int GetMinimumColumnCount(List <RowEntity> dataRows)
    {
        int minColCount;
        FileEntity fileObj = new FileEntity(); // to access the rows from the Excel file
        int headerLines; // can be changed but here set in given example

        // calculate the minColumnCount for the 

        return minColCount; 
    }
```

Any idea how?

Comment: do you want the same appearance like you mentioned above in the question?

Comment: Same appearance? I didn't understand what exactly you mean.

Comment: 1 a
2 b c
3 d e f
4 g h i j k
5 l m n

Comment: No, what I need is to get the minimum column count, which is 3 in the example. Only need the Common Column Count from all the rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it sorted eventually

The reason for using nullable int type is that the very first value can be null but having it 0 initially will never do the check right.

```
    private int? GetMinimumColumnCount(List <RowEntity> dataRows)
    {
        int ? minColumnCount = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < dataRows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (minColumnCount == null || minColumnCount > dataRows[i].ColumnValues.Count) 
            {
                minColumnCount = dataRows[i].ColumnValues.Count; 
            }     
        }
        return minColumnCount; 
    }
```